# Why does this before_filter not execute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, before-filter

So in my `ClientsController.rb` I have a before filter that does the following:

Checks the current year, and month. If the month is after June, then set the variable `vote_year` to next year. If it isn't, then set the `vote_year` to this year.

Then I am setting the date attribute based on that year, along with the hard month & day of July 1.

Basically, this particular date is on July 1st every year. I want this before filter to set the next date based on whether or not the time that this filter has been run is before or after July 1st.

The code I have is as follows:

```
before_filter :set_next_vote_date, :only => [:create, :new, :edit, :update]

private

def set_next_vote_date
    client = current_user.clients.find(params[:id])
    today = DateTime.parse(Time.now.to_s)
    year = today.year

    if today.month == 7 && today.day == 1
        vote_year = today.year
    elsif today.month > 6
        vote_year = year + 1
    else
        vote_year = year
    end

    client.next_vote = "#{vote_year}-07-01"         
end
```

The issue is that there is no error thrown, whenever I do any of those actions on those controllers. But, the `next_vote` attribute on the client record is not being updated.

What am I missing?

**Edit 1:**

After I have used `update_attribute` (without the `!`), I don't get an error, but I am not seeing this particular attribute being updated in the log.

```
Started PUT "/clients/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-08 20:09:17 -0500
Processing by ClientsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"J172LuZQc5N=", "client"=>{"name"=>"John F Kennedy", "email"=>"jfk@email.com", "phone"=>"8234698765", "firm_id"=>"1", "topic_ids"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Update Client", "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Client Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."user_id" = 1 AND "clients"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."user_id" = 1 AND "clients"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Topic Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "topics".* FROM "topics" WHERE "topics"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Topic Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "topics".* FROM "topics" INNER JOIN "clients_topics" ON "topics"."id" = "clients_topics"."topic_id" WHERE "clients_topics"."client_id" = 1
   (0.4ms)  UPDATE "clients" SET "phone" = 823498765, "updated_at" = '2012-09-09 01:09:17.631839' WHERE "clients"."id" = 1
   (1.4ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/clients/1
```

Note that the `next_vote` attribute isn't updated. Granted, I didn't include that attribute in the `edit` form partial, but I assumed that this `before_filter` - if it is being executed, would update the record. But I am not even sure if it is being executed at all.

**Edit 2:**

Never mind, it seems to be working now. The above log paste was AFTER the edit action, and the before_filter executes before the edit action - DUH! Silly me :)

Comment: Looks to me like you're missing `client.save`. Unless that gets called later in the controller actions.

Are you sure this code is not being executed, or is it just that the record attribute isn't being updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're not saving the client after changing the attribute.

Some further suggestions on how to clean up that code a bit:

```
before_filter :set_next_vote_date, :only => [:create, :new, :edit, :update]

private

def set_next_vote_date
  client    = current_user.clients.find(params[:id])
  today     = Date.today
  vote_year = today.month > 6 ? today.year + 1 : today.year

  client.update_attribute(:next_vote, Date.new(vote_year, 7, 1))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
def set_next_vote_date
  client = Client.find(params[:id])
  today = Time.now
  year = today.year

  if today.month == 7 && today.day == 1
    vote_year = year
  elsif today.month > 6
    vote_year = year + 1
  else
    vote_year = year
  end

  client.update_attribute!(:next_vote, "#{vote_year}-07-01")
end
```

the update_attribute! (note the bang) will cause an exception to be raised if something goes wrong.. atleast allowing you to rescue with pry-rescue and see what's going on.  a call to save shouldn't be necessary, as it will be persisted later in the activerecord callback cycle.

Comment: Now I am getting this error: `undefined method `update_attribute!' for #<Client:0x007fd0ae30dc80>, NoMethodError in ClientsController#edit`. Around line:   `client.update_attribute!(:next_vote, "#{vote_year}-07-01")`

Comment: By the way, once I try `update_attribute` it works. But with the `!`, it doesn't. This is the log with the bang: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'update_attribute!' for #<Client:0x007fd0ac6ea058>):
  app/controllers/clients_controller.rb:102:in 'set_next_vote_date'`

Comment: sorry, there is no bang method for update_attribute, i was incorrect.  you would want to use update_attributes!(params) passing in the params hash.

Comment: I actually did a re-factor and moved this functionality into my Model - and did a `before_save` callback instead. Thanks though.